# Can't use iadd within a python class

Tags: python, class

I am trying to understand why I can't use iadd (+=) within a class on the self object.

For example, if I define a class with iadd and a function which uses iadd (addA):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return A(self.n+other.n)
    def addA(self, other):
        self+=other

a1 = A(9)
a2 = A(8)
```

If I use the addA function, a1 doesn't seem to be affected:

```
a1.addA(a2)
print a1.n
>>> 9
```

However if I use iadd normally, it works ok:

```
a1+=a2
print a1.n
>>> 17
```

Can someone tell me how I can use iadd within a class definition.

(Hopefully this is not relevant but I'm asking this as I'm trying to make a wrapper for the maya.OpenMaya.MMatrix object - I'd like to add a function to apply an arbitary transformation. I need to use the iadd function inside my class definition as I don't have direct access to the data stored in the parent class, but I can manipulate it using iadd.)

Answer (score 3):

`__iadd__` is returning a new instance of `A` and not modifying the original instance.  Try this to see:

```
a1.addA(a2)
print a1.n
print a1.__iadd__(a2).n
```

Use this definition of A to get the behavior you are after:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.n += other.n
        return self
    def addA(self, other):
        self+=other
```

Answer (score 3):

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__):

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (**modifying
>   self**) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be,
>   self)

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, n):
   ...:         self.n = n
   ...:     def __iadd__(self, other):
   ...:         self.n = self.n + other.n
   ...:         return self
   ...:     def addA(self, other):
   ...:         self += other
   ...:         

In [2]: a1 = A(9)

In [3]: a2 = A(8)

In [4]: a1.addA(a2)

In [5]: a1.n
Out[5]: 17
```